# Script to search inside links in a webpage

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Is it possible to write a script in greasemonkey that will find specific/mentioned keyword on the list of given links for example a page has 10 links and am looking for word "ramp" and on those 10links can it go and highlight the links that has word "ramp" ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a rather broad question; you might want to post some code examples of what you currently have and a more detailed explanation of the problems you're facing. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation. As the other say, your question should not be asked this way.
I assume that you don't know Javascript, so here is a quick and dirty code that solves your issue.

```
"use strict";
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (let i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    let link = links[i];
    link.innerHTML = link.innerHTML.replace("ramp", "<span style='background-color: yellow;'>ramp</span>");
}
```

Now that you have the code, I advice you to spend some time on the following links:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML 
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: Thank You for the support   .